# Textbox Maxlength Issue for amount field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation having a textbox having 15 as a max length property. That field works as a amount field. it is working correctly in normal cases.

lets say if i enter **11234567890.99** this amount in textbox it displays it as **112,34,567,890.99** which is expected.

But, if i copy & paste **112,34,567,890.99** amount in textbox last two digits gets truncated because the length gets out of bound.

Is there any ways to change this without modifying the exact behavior? allowing to paste whole **112,34,567,890.99** amount.

```js
     $(document).on("focusout","#txtformate1",(function () {
            if (this.value != null && this.value != "") {
                $((this.parentElement).nextElementSibling).hide()
            }
            else{
                $((this.parentElement).nextElementSibling).show()
            }
        }));
     $(document).on('keyup', '.Amt', function () {

                var val = $(this).val();
                val = val.replace(/([~!#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,\/? ])+/g, '');

                if(isNaN(val) && val!="-")
                {
                    val="";
                }
                $(this).val(val);
                /*if (isNaN(val)) {
                    val = val.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
                    if(val.indexOf("-")>-1)
                    {
                        val = val.replace(/[`*\/]/g, '');
                    }
                    else{val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');}

                    if (val.split('.').length > 2)
                    {
                        val = val.replace(/\.+$/, "");
                    }
                    else if(val==".")
                    {
                        val ="";
                    }
                }*/


            });

            $(document).on('focusout', '.Amt', function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                val = val.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
                if(isNaN(val) && val.indexOf(',')>-1){
                    val=$(this).val();
                }
                if (val == "0.00"){
                    val="";
                }
                $(this).val(val);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control Amt" id="txtformate1" maxlength="15" />`
```

Comment: Share your HTML

Comment: Add dynamic length on `keyup`

Comment: Html and script code posted @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: Can you suggest a code for it? i dont want a dynamic lenght. length should be fixed to 15 chars @CoolJK

Comment: Rather than onfocus use keypree .. I hope it works.
Thanks !!

Comment: `if i enter 11234567890.99 this amount in textbox it displays it as 112,34,567,890.99` Displays it where?